# Difference between golang.org packages and the standard library

Tags: go

I've been using go for a short time now, and I've been noticing that there are duplicate packages between Go (standard library) and golang.org/x/.

My questions are: Why are they released twice? And of the two, which one should I use (more up-to-date, canonical, etc)?

Some sample packages that are released twice that I've noticed so far:

- `golang.org/x/net/html` vs `net/html`
- `golang.org/x/crypto` vs `crypto`
- and maybe more that I can't remember right now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/#subrepo

> These packages are part of the Go Project but outside the main Go tree.
> They are developed under looser compatibility requirements than the Go core.

Use the standard library packages unless you have a strong need to use the `/x/` variant and can accept the risk of breaking changes.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the packages in the `golang.org/x/` namespace used to live only there, then were later adopted into the standard library. For backward compatibility, the `golang.org/x/` version remains.

New apps should always use the standard library version, though, unless there's a compelling reason otherwise (such as using a library that still uses the old version).